# UWP - How to convert a ResourceDictionary XAML Style to C#

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I am trying to create a C# version of a XAML Style, but I'm struggling to add the `ContentPresenter/ContentTemplate` and `VisualStateManagers`. Surely this shouldn't be difficult, but it is proving so.

E.g. how would I create a C# version of this..

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundBaseLowBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseHighBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0,0,0,2" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="12,8,12,8" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Left" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Center" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="{ThemeResource ContentControlThemeFontFamily}" />
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{ThemeResource TextStyleLargeFontSize}" />
        <Setter Property="UseSystemFocusVisuals" Value="False" />
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid"
                          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <Border x:Name="FocusOuterRectangle"
                                Margin="-3,-3,0,0"
                                BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}"
                                BorderThickness="3,3,3,1">
                            <ContentPresenter x:Name="ContentPresenter"
                                              Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                                              HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                              VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"
                                              BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                                              BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                                              Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"
                                              ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
                                              ContentTransitions="{TemplateBinding ContentTransitions}"
                                              FontSize="{TemplateBinding FontSize}"
                                              TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" />
                        </Border>
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource myButtonBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource myBlackBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource myWhiteBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusOuterRectangle"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource myButtonHoverBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource myBlackBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ContentPresenter"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource myWhiteBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="FocusOuterRectangle"
                                                                       Storyboard.TargetProperty="BorderBrush">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0"
                                                                    Value="{StaticResource SystemControlForegroundTransparentBrush}" />
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <PointerUpThemeAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" />
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

So far I've got this:

```
var style = new Style();
style.TargetType = typeof(Button);
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BackgroundProperty, Brushes.MyButtonBrush));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.MyWhiteBrush));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BorderBrushProperty, Brushes.MyBlackBrush));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.BorderThicknessProperty, new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 2)));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.PaddingProperty, new Thickness(12, 8, 12, 8)));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Left));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.VerticalAlignmentProperty, VerticalAlignment.Center));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.FontFamilyProperty, FontFamily.XamlAutoFontFamily));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.FontWeightProperty, FontWeights.Normal));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.FontSizeProperty, TextStyleLargeFontSize));
style.Setters.Add(new Setter(Button.UseSystemFocusVisualsProperty, false));

var controlTemplate = new ControlTemplate { TargetType = typeof(Button) };

var contentPresenter = new ContentPresenter
{
    Name = "ContentPresenter",
    Padding = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 2),
    HorizontalContentAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Left,
    VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center,
    BorderBrush = Brushes.MyBlackBrush,
    BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 0, 0, 2),
    FontSize = TextStyleLargeFontSize,
    TextWrapping = TextWrapping.WrapWholeWords
};
```

But I'm unsure how to add the `ContentPresenter` to the `ControlTemplate`, or to create a `Grid` that contains the `ContentPresenter`. Then I'm unsure how to begin creating the `VisualStateGroups` etc.

Many thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible to write equivalent code in the code-behind. In WPF the `ControlTemplate` had a `VisualTree` property that allowed to set it in code-behind and you also could use `FrameworkElementFactory` to create subclasses of `FrameworkTemplate` such as `ControlTemplate` or `DataTemplate`, but these options were incomplete and didn't provide all of the XAML flexibility. Instead, you can use the [`XamlReader` class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.markup.xamlreader) to parse XAML code from a `string` at runtime. This way you may be able to create it in code-behind, but I don't see many reasons for doing so over just using the XAML code you already have.